# Is orphan removal possible with Hibernate OneToMany ManyToMany sets depending on same entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, one-to-many, orphan

I have two entities A, B.
A contains OneToMany set that includes entity A's ID and C's ID.
B contains ManyToMany set that includes entity B's ID and C's ID.

If A is removed, C mapped by A should also be removed even if C is mapped by B.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Orphan removal doesn't apply when you remove the owning entity, but when you remove the owned entity from its owning entity.

Comment: C is mapped by A and B. C should be removed if A is removed even if C is mapped by B.

Comment: Show us code, and explain what you want to do. Your terminology is not clear, and orphanRemoval doesn't do what you think it does.